# TransactionTooLargeException and FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION when trying to pick images in Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

I'm using 3 fragments to show in a tab layout, the next problem refers to one of those fragments.

I'm trying to pick single or multiple images in my app, I open the image picker using a button and the next code:

```
btn_galeria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 10);
            }
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

But as soon as the image picker opens, the app either has one of these outcomes:

- Using Android emulator API 23: logcat shows
  `E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2572096)` `the image picker shows up and the app keeps running, I'm able to select the images and the app work as expected.
- Using physical device Huawei P30 Lite API 29: same error `E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 6639520)`, but this time, even though the image picker shows up, the app crashes in the background with the next reason:

```
2020-07-07 02:02:51.311 31240-31240/com.ssp.atencionvictimas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ssp.atencionvictimas, PID: 31240
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 6639520 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 6639520 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:526)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4561)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101) 
2020-07-07 02:02:51.317 31240-31240/com.ssp.atencionvictimas I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31240 SIG: 9
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to let the user pick one or multiple images (if possible maximum 6) and show the selected images using a view adapter already made.

This is the code which executes after the user has selected the image or images:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Esta sección de código se ejecuta cuando se termina un Intent, y se regresa al Activity anterior

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
            ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();
            ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> ListaUris = new ArrayList<>();

            if(clipdata != null) {
                for(int i=0; i<clipdata.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Uri imageUri = clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    mArrayUri.add(imageUri);

                    try {
                        InputStream is = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "URI DE IMAGEN: " + imageUri);

                        // Will return "image:x*"
                        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(imageUri);

                        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                        String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        // where id is equal to
                        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

                        String filePath = "";
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        }

                        cursor.close();
                        ListaUris.add(filePath);

                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "FILEPATH: " + filePath);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                mArrayUri.add(imageUri);

                try {
                    InputStream is = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "URI DE IMAGEN: " + imageUri);

                    // Will return "image:x*"
                    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(imageUri);

                    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    // where id is equal to
                    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

                    String filePath = "";
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    }

                    cursor.close();
                    ListaUris.add(filePath);

                    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "FILEPATH: " + filePath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mArrayUri);
            gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
            gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                    .getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);

            Log.v("LOG_TAG", "CANTIDAD DE FOTOS: " + ListaUris.size());
            Log.v("LOG_TAG", "LISTA DE URIS: " + ListaUris);
        }

    }
```

But even if I comment out the previous code, same behaviour occurs, so I believe it has something to do with the way the intent returns or handles the gallery data.

Comment: If you comment out all the code in `onActivityResult()` your app still crashes with the "failed binder transaction" error?

Comment: @DavidWasser I am having the same issue, and I have commented out everything in onActivityResult()
And I am trying to select 1000+ images.

Comment: I don't know why you think that this will work if you select 1000 images. Anyway, I don't understand the things you are telling me as they don't make sense. You'll need to strip your code down and add parts back, step by step, until it crashes, then maybe you can isolate the problem. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @DavidWasser I solved it, you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by adding the next method override on the fragment class:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (outState != null)
            outState.clear();
    }
```